# Проверка на наличие нескольких элементов в массиве

Tags: php

Как в PHP проверить на наличие нескольких массивов в элементе $row[]?
К примеру есть массив следующего описания:

```
$array = [
'item1' => 'new, ussr',
'item2' => 'new',
'item' => 'old'
];
```

Так вот, как получить все элементы где содержание = 'new, ussr'?

Comment: можешь пример приложить? не очень понятно что ты хочешь

Comment: обновил вопрос  ы

Comment: row из базы получаете?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = [];

array_walk($array, function ($v, $k) use (&$res) {
        if ($v === 'new, ussr'){
            $res[$k] = $v;
        }
    });

print_r($res);
```